# Java application with SQLite not saving operations on a specific computer after closing, .sqlite-journal not flushing

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans-8, sqlitestudio

I made a simple application for registering, deleting and searching for users using java + sqlite (netbeans and sqlite studio).
I tested on 3 computers and everything worked correctly, however on a specific computer the behavior is:

- I open the application once, I perform some insertion and / or deletion operations, I close the app and everything is ok.
- I open the application again and I make more insertions and / or deletions and everything is ok.
- I open again and from the moment I perform any operation, a .sqlite-journal file is created in the folder that when it is created all the operations I do are no longer saved. I close the application and it is still there. When I reopen the changes were not saved.

This happens only on this specific pc, in others the .sqlite-journal file is not created and everything works ok.

I've read this on sqlite website:

"SQLite normally stores all content in a single disk file. However, while performing a transaction, information necessary to roll back that transaction following a crash or power failure is stored in auxiliary journal files. These journal files have the same name as the original database file with the addition of -journal or -wal suffix.

SQLite must see the journal files in order to recover from a crash or power failure. If the journal files are moved, deleted, or renamed after a crash or power failure, then automatic recovery will not work and the database may go corrupt."

And I saw on the internet that in sqlite everything is already set to autocommit and sometimes it can go wrong and it saves in that journal. I already took the autocommit and manually put in the code to commit after each operation, but it did not solve.

The code for deletion is (the insertion is similar):

private void cmd_deletarintActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    int p = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Você realmente quer deletar?", "Delete", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

```
if (p==0) {
String sql = "delete from EleitoresInterior where id=?";

try {
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setString(1, txt_idint.getText());
    pst.execute();
    conn.commit();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dados apagados!");
}
catch(Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    try {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.rollback();
        }
    } catch (Exception e2) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Problemas na conexão!");
    }
}
finally{
    try{
        pst.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
}
Update_table2();
}
```

}

In that code, when I run the application, after the journal file is created it drops in the message "Problemas na conexão!", so at some point the connection is null, which is causing the error.

Comment: What is the filesystem on that machine?

Comment: it's NTFS like the other pc's

Comment: Over a network share?

Comment: everything is local